# is there any difference between these two pieces of code? (temp variable)

Tags: c++, constructor

Is there any difference between these two pieces of code?

```
CPoint temp(x,y);

some_func(temp);
```

and

```
some_func(CPoint(x,y));
```

Comment: `temp` is an lvalue whereas the temporary object in the second one is an rvalue. This may affect overload resolution for `some_func`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the first case, the temp var will not be destroyed until the end of the scope. In the second case it will be.

If your function `some_func()` takes a non const reference as a parameter, the second will not compile since you can not have a reference to something which will be destroyed right away (when `some_func` returns).

In the first case, if your `some_func()` function takes a reference, you should be aware that the `temp` variable will only exist until the current scope ends.

Comment: You can have an rvalue reference to something that will be destroyed right away. This is actually very useful, as in those circumstances you can move from the object that is about to be destroyed.

Comment: Oh yes, it will possible only if the reference is const, right?

Comment: @arthur.sw: No, Matt refers to `some_func(CPoint&&)`.

Comment: Ok, I did not know about it before reading [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of the CPoint objects is different.

In the first case, a variable named 'temp' is created. It will not be destroyed until after the scope within which it is declared is exited.

In the second case, a true temporary value is created and passed to the function, which will be destroyed as soon as some_func has returned.